(In)equality proof assistant
Is there any user-friendly proof assistant that helps proving long, complex (in)equalities?
Disclaimer: I have never used any proof assistant before. I am sure that usual proof assistants would do the job, but since they are designed to be super-general, they might not be very user-friendly for such a simple (is it?) task.
Let us consider an example to explain what I would like it to do. Consider the following proof (the result of which is well-known and not interesting for my question):
Let $f$ and $g$ be two measurable functions on a measure space. We then have: $(f + g)^2 \leq (\vert f \vert + \vert g \vert)^2 \leq (2\max\{\vert f \vert, \vert g \vert\})^2 = 4\max\{\vert f \vert^2, \vert g \vert^2\} \leq 4(\vert f \vert^2 + \vert g \vert^2)$. Therefore, $\Vert f+g\Vert^2_2 \leq 4(\Vert f \Vert^2_2 + \Vert g \Vert^2_2)$.
Then I could say to the proof assistant:

$f$ and $g$ are maps;
we start with $(f+g)^2$;
begin by asserting the inequality obtained by replacing $f$ and $g$ by their absolute value;
use the lemma (that we have proved or assumed somewhere else) that says $\forall x,y,\quad \vert x \vert + \vert y \vert \leq 2\max\{\vert x \vert , \vert y \vert\}$ to what is being squared;
etc.

and the proof assistant would return a program that could be compiled by anyone wanting to check the proof. I may also provide a $\LaTeX$ version of the proof. It would be very useful if the proof assistant was able to do some simple formal calculus (simplify rational fractions, for example) and maybe knew how to handle $o(\cdot)$ and more generally, usual real analysis stuff.

You might find more useful responses on https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/.  My limited experience with Isabelle is that a proof of the kind you describe would be reasonably straighforward, especially if you had the Analysis library loaded. Indeed, this theorem might well already be in there.

Oh, I didn't know that this website even existed! Thank you very much. The inequality I wrote was just an example to show that when proving an inequality, you use some lemmas on things that are nested deep in the term; I realize my question isn't very clear.

Your question is fine. And as I said, I think that this is pretty simple in Isabelle (although I'm enough of a beginner that in trying to do it, I'm finding out I can't remember how to load the Analysis library, and whether it's already part of "Main". :(

BTW, I think it's also pretty simple in Lean, although again, I've used it seldom enough that I cannot write out the Lean "theory file" to demonstrate that.

You say you "only" care about (in)equalities, but for a proof assistant to be able to handle that, it will also have to know a lot about sets, functions, real and complex numbers (hence also things like completeness) etc. So I doubt it's feasible to build a proof assistant for this case that is significantly "simpler" than the general ones. From my experience, Lean's "calc"-tactic provides a pretty intuitive and user-friendly way to deal with (in)equalities.

@anankElpis: Really? I don't know how to express this in precise logical terms, but I thought that this part of analysis was "logically" much less complex than general mathematics.

Of course it depends how difficult the inequalities get. If you only want to do algebraic multiplications, maybe with some assumptions thrown in, then maybe you don't need a large framework. But if you want to state or prove some more complicated analysis results, the individual arguments for each step in the inequality chain will require more logic.

Agda's (in)equational reasoning combinators are well-suited for this kind of thing (see e.g. this).
